# Angular JS format date

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a datetimepicker in one of my inputs and it returns this:

```
"2016-11-15T19:44:33.984Z"
```

I am trying to format it in my view, I have tried the following:

```
{{user.dob | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

but it still returns `"2016-11-15T19:44:33.984Z"`

Comment: That's because it's a string, not a date. Convert it to date first.

Comment: @user1655756 the documentation says that a string can be accepted too: `Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: You are right. Update the question with the controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any issues with your filter code.

You can check this sample

```
<pre>Formatted date with angular filter (date:'yyyy-MM-dd') : <em>{{dt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</em></pre>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CXfRqc56RM9VFoJevXZd?p=preview)

If you are thinking something else then plz provide Plunker sample